# Electorate badge not acquired yet, so how can I know if I am eligible for it or not

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

I want to know why I haven't got Electorate Badge. I think I fulfill its requirements: I have almost 750+ votes and around 39 percent Votes on question but I still don't have the badge.

I think I am entitled to that badge. If I am not, then how much more percentage do I require to get that badge?

Following is link to my profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045808/noobie-php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You say you have 750+ votes, and 39% of them are on questions. That means you've got around 292 votes on questions alone. The badge requires 600 votes on questions alone, *and* 25% of all your voting history has to be on questions.

So yes, you fulfill the requirement for the percentage currently. But you have 307 question votes to go before the badge is awarded.

Comment: `Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions` , so what does this means? i mean it just says 600 questions and and 25 percent or more are on questions

Comment: It means just that; you need to vote on 600 questions, and it looks like you have only 298 votes on questions. Answer votes don't count! You'll basically have the 25% requirement once you hit 600 questions and have less than 1800 answer votes.

Comment: @noobie-php To earn the badge, you need to cast 600 question votes. Then once you've reached 600 question votes, 25% of all of your votes (on both questions and answers) must be on questions. Maybe reading [this answer on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) (find the Electorate heading in the answer) could bring some clarification?

Comment: @noobie-php - You can see how many question votes you have on your profile by scrolling to the bottom and finding the "Votes Cast" section on the right. You'll be looking for the "by type" part.